# iPython3 opened in Terminal - os.path.dir adds letter 'd' to path and triggers File not found error

Tags: command-line, python3, paths, ipython

Trying to iterate through a folder. 
I am working on ipython3, opened in Terminal.
This is the code (in python 3.6.4):

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    for file in filename:
       with open(os.path.join('.',file), 'r') as f:
            print(len(f))
```

However I get this error.

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1702c8aca957> in <module>()
  1 for filename in os.listdir('.'):
  2     for file in filename:
----> 3         with open(os.path.join('.',file), 'r') as f:
  4             print(len(f))
  5 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './d'
```

A 'd' is added to the path and the directory cannot be found.
The same happens with Jupypter QtConsole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns a list of file names. With the

```
for file in filename
```

loop you are iterating over the letters in this file names, and the first file name found seems to start with a `'d'`. Remove this loop.

Later in your code

```
print(len(f))
```

will throw an exception as you can't use `len` with a file handle. If you want to get the size of the file use [os.path.getsize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize)